# SCCM - Query Powershell Version

Tags: sccm, query

I am trying to create create a query in SCCM to show how many computers are installed with the different Powershell-versions. I suspect we have a mix of v2,v3 and v4, but I need to know how many and their computer names. Does anyone know how I can accomplish this? I couldnt find anything about this online.

I would prefer a query because I dont want to make a report (I am not comfertable with the report builder in SCCM 2012).

Comment: Have you done much with creating custom collections yet?

Comment: Yes I've done that, but that will also require a query?

Comment: Good question.  [This Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29665724/determine-powershell-version-remotely-via-wmi) makes me think there isn't a WMI query that easily reveals the WMF version.  I _think_ installations of WMF versions higher than the one in the RTM have all been distributed as Windows Updates.  For example, WMF 4 for Windows 7 [is KB2819745](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2819745).  If that is the case you should be able to infer WMF version from the OS version and whether any of the WMF updates is installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this if you enable the Software Inventory function in your client settings.
By default SINV disables scanning of `C:\Windows` so you need to re-enable the Powershell path `%windir%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0`
After that, you can create Queries or Collections that leverage the "Softare Files" attribute class to see what you have. So far I've mapped out the following values & version numbers.

```
v1,2 Less Than 6.2
v3   Like      6.2.%
v4   Like      6.3.%
```

[image: Clientsettings]
[image: ClientSettings2]
[image: QueryCriteria]